# Display Count of Entries posted today

Tags: templating

I'm trying to display a notification badge on how many new entries were posted today only. But I cannot get the following to work.

```
{% set timeAgo = now|dateModify('today') %}

{% set recentMerchantsOffers = craft.entries.section('offers').postDate(timeAgo).relatedTo(recentMerchants) %}
```

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `recentlyViewed()` is and what it returns but to query today's entry, you can do:

```
{# Today in atom format #}
{% set timeAgo = date('today') | atom %}

{% set recentMerchantsOffers = craft.entries()
    .section('offers')
    .postDate(">= #{timeAgo}")
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Sorry was a relic bit of code. Your solution worked like a charm!